# Calculate velocity $\nu$.

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

A lorry of mass $3.5\times10^4\text{ kg}$ attains a steady speed $\nu$ while climbing an incline of $1$ in $10$ with its engine operating at $175$ kW. Find $\nu$. $g=10ms^{-1}$. Neglect friction.

The answer in the book is $5.0ms^{-1}$.

### Attempt 1:

All the power goes into the sum of potential and kinetic energies. 
$$175000=\frac{1}{2}m\nu^{2}+mgh$$
Relating $h$ to $\nu$ on given slope, $\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{\nu}{10}$

$$\nu^2 +2\nu -10=0$$
$$\nu=2.32,-4.32 ms^{-1}$$

Not sure what to make of that result.

### Attempt 2:

The force component due to gravity perpendicular to the slope is $mg\sin\theta=m=35000N$. The power of the lorry can exert $175000Nms^{-1}$. The resultant force of $140000N$ must go into momentum. $140000=m\nu$. Therefore $\nu=4.0ms^{-1}$.

This attempt gives a nicer value but is not the same as the book. Did I make a calculation mistake? Could the answer in the book be wrong?

Comment: I suppose you should ask this on www.physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: You are right Harsh. I posted in the wrong section.

Comment: In Attempt 1 you are equating power with energy and in Attempt 2 you are equating power with force.  You can either do power = energy/time = $mg\frac {dh}{dt}$ or power=force $\times$ velocity.  In both cases the units work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lorry is moving at constant speed so the forces are in equilibrium. Therefore you have $$\frac Pv=mg\sin\theta$$

Plugging in the values, you get $v=5$

Comment: Wow , that was a lot simpler than I was making it out to be.